# Gnuplot with image: clip data above a specified maximum

Tags: plot, gnuplot, color-mapping

Say I have an xyz data file, with z values going from 0 to 10. I produce a colormap of the data like so:

```
plot xyz.dat with image
```

How do I set the maximum to say, 5, so that all data values > 5 are color coded as if they were 5?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clip the color range is using a fixed maximum value:

```
set cbrange [0:5]
plot 'xyz.dat' with image
```

If you have a more complicated expression for the clipping, you can do any kind of computation and tests inside the `using` statement:

```
plot 'xyz.dat' using 1:2:($3 > 5 ? 5 : $3) with image
```

The `$3` is a shorthand for `column(3)`, which provides the numerical value of the third column.